# How can I enable cross-origin AJAX requests between my chrome extension and my Node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension

In my `background.js` script, I'm making vanilla AJAX GET request using the `XMLHttpRequest()` object to my Node server (currently hosted on `localhost`). The Node server is using the npm package `express` to handle the GET request. However, `background.js` just returns the error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:80' from origin 'chrome-extension://jhccmehanjenpnjalilnihdmeignbcpn' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Is it a permission I need to include in the `manifest.json` or something? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you didn't specify `http://` before localhost.

Comment: @wOxxOm that solved my problem thanks! I don't have the capability to test my Node server hosted on externally right now but as long as I include the domain/IP in the ```manifest.json``` it should work the same right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wOxxOm solved my problem in the comment above! I just forgot the `http://`